# sln monotouch sample Load failed

Tags: xcode4, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

monotouch sample solution fails to load

this solution gives me a load error. downloaded from here.

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started/intro_to_mvc_in_ios
http://xamarin.com/pdf/Transitioning_from_Xcode_3_to_Xcode_4_in_Monotouch.pdf

here is a screenshot.

do I have to download a different version of monodevelop? how do i check the version of monotouch?

[image]

thanks

Comment: This is unrelated to the MonoTouch version but if/when you want to know it (it can prove useful) just run "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --version" from a terminal window

Comment: I got an error when opening the xib file until I updated monotouch to     --- mtouch 4.0.7.0 EVALUATION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to download MonoDevelop 2.8 alpha to work with the Xcode 4 support. If you go to "Help -> Check for updates", change the drop down to "Alpha" and it should allow you to download the latest MonoDevelop 2.8 alpha version.

It's worth installing MonoDevelop 2.8 side by side with MonoDevelop 2.4.2 (although, it might be worth trying out the MonoDevelop 2.6 support in the Beta channel too instead of 2.4.2 - this doesn't support Xcode 4 though).

Hope this helps,

ChrisNTR